# Avoid relative public path in Vue

Tags: vue.js

In vue.config.js I've declared the following publicpath:

```
publicPath: '/mobile'
```

and I've a logout button that should point to an url outside the publicPath I've set:

```
<v-btn
  text
  small
  color="teal"
  to="/accounts/logout"
>
  <v-icon>mdi-logout</v-icon>Tancar Sessió
</v-btn>
```

This should point to `localhost/accounts/logout`, but instead it's pointing to `localhost/mobile/accounts/logout`.

How can I avoid the `publicPath` reference and at the same time avoid setting an absolute path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically doing this would be anti-semantic but you could do something like this.

```
  text
  small
  color="teal"
  to=""
  href="/accounts/logout"
>
  <v-icon>mdi-logout</v-icon>Tancar Sessió
</v-btn>
```

Leave the `to` prop in the vuetify button empty, forcing it to render as a link, and if you look at the source code, when the path is null, vuetify does not render the `href` attribute. Thus the href passed by you does not get overridden.